# How can one combine pyramid_beaker decorator-style caching and pyramid_tm?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, transactions, pyramid, beaker

With Pyramid / `pyramid_tm` I end up passing around the `dbsession` object that joined the current transaction to methods that encapsulate my code. For example

```
def get_item_name(dbsession, item_id):
    item = dbsession.query(...)
    return item.name

def view_func(request):
    item_name = get_item_name(request.dbsession, request.GET['item_id']
    ...
```

Now if I wanted to cache the results of `get_item_name` using the beaker cache decorator `@cache_region` for example, I would never get a cache hit since `dbsession` is part of the cache key.

What is a common pattern to solve this elegantly?

Comment: Since pyramid, I am using dogpile cache for caching. I am pretty sure it has some mechanism to ignore the first argument when calculating the key, but I cannot find any documentation :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one pattern is to decorate a closure that only accepts the args you want to cache and accesses other variables like request/dbsession from nonlocal scope.

```
def view_func(request):
    @cache.region('short_term')
    def get_item_name(item_id):
        item = request.dbsession.query(...)
        return item.name
    item_name = get_item_name(request.GET['item_id'])
```

This pattern is common in the beaker docs.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, that's also the only solution that I came up with spontaneously.